# Is this always true that $[x-1]=[x]-1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is this always true that $[x-1]=[x]-1$, where [] denotes greatest integer function

Comment: Yes, it is. Try to visualize a line with dots (integers).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is.

Let $x$ be a real number such that $m\leq x<m+1$ where $m\in\mathbb{Z}$.
What is $\lfloor x\rfloor$? What is $\lfloor x-1\rfloor$?

Answer (score 3):

$$[x-1]\leq x-1<[x-1]+1\implies [x-1]+1\leq x<[x-1]+2\implies[x]=[x-1]+1$$

The second implication because $[x-1]+1$ and $[x-1]+2$ are integers.

Comment: Why you chose $[x] = [x-1]+1$ instead of $[x-1]+2$?

Comment: @Navaro Because it concerns the [greatest integer function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GreatestIntegerFunction.html), which is by definition the [floor function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FloorFunction.html).